# What ember-cli dependencies should be used for Ember 1.12?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

As you know Ember-cli 0.2.7 is the last release with Ember 1.12 (with Ember-data 1.0.0-beta.18). Next release is based on Ember 1.13 (with Ember-data 1.13).

What if I am not ready to use Ember 1.13, waiting for some addons, but ready to use Ember-Data 1.13.

Should I stay on default Ember-cli 0.2.7 dependencies list (even with Ember-Data "1.0.0-beta.18")? If not, what dependencies could be updated? Or may be I could use Ember-cli 1.13 with Ember version changed?

Below are standard `package.json` and `bower.json` files extractions for Ember-cli 0.2.7 and 1.13.

```
//ember-cli 0.2.7, standard package.json  
"devDependencies": {
  "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
  "ember-cli": "0.2.7",
  "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.3",
  "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
  "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
  "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.0.0",
  "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.6",
  "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
  "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
  "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.13",
  "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.0.1",
  "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.18",
  "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.0",
  "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2"
}

//ember-cli 0.2.7, standard bower.json 
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.12.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.18",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.4",
    "ember-qunit": "0.3.3",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.15",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1"
}

// ember-cli 1.13, standard package.json 
"devDependencies": {
  "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
  "ember-cli": "1.13.0",
  "ember-cli-app-version": "0.4.0",
  "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
  "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
  "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.0.0",
  "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.9",
  "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.1.1",
  "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.2.1",
  "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
  "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.15",
  "ember-cli-release": "0.2.3",
  "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.0.1",
  "ember-data": "1.13.5",
  "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.0",
  "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2"
}

// ember-cli 1.13, standard bower.json 
"dependencies": {
  "ember": "1.13.3",
  "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
  "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
  "ember-data": "1.13.5",
  "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.5",
  "ember-qunit": "0.4.1",
  "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
  "ember-resolver": "~0.1.18",
  "jquery": "^1.11.1",
  "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
  "qunit": "~1.17.1"
}
```

Comment: Personally I ran CLI 0.2.7 with Ember 1.13 and Data 1.13 with no issues other than a couple of deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this file in the Ember data 1.13.5 release https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.13.5/packages/ember-data/lib/main.js

It suggests two things:

1) You need at least Ember 1.8.0 to use Ember Data 1.13(.5).

2) There was a bug issue with Ember 1.12.0 and Ember data, but Ember 1.12.1 should be ok.

I'd give CLI 0.27, Ember 1.12.1 and Ember data 1.13.5 a go if your not ready for Ember 1.13.

Comment: Thanks for helpful info. What do you think about using ember-cli 1.13 with ember 1.12.1?

Comment: I can spot at least one change in Ember CLI 1.13 that depends on Ember 1.13: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/4359. That's was the quickest one to spot, there could be others https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v1.13.0. Given this and that it has Ember 1.13 in it's package.json I wouldn't myself

Comment: ember-cli 1.13 should work with any ember prolly down to 1.9 or so, some of the generators/blueprints just might not work but it isn't tied to ember internals